# problems working with vectors to find common element

Tags: c++, visual-c++, object, vector, stdvector

i am trying to find the common elements(song_list) between two vectors, in my user.h file i have two vectors and am trying to use this vectors in another class(help.cpp) but i cant get it right. please whats wrong with my code? it doesn't run and am not entirely sure if this is the right approach.

### user.h

```
   #pragma once
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    class User
  {

public:

User(void);
~User(void);


      public:


struct user1
      {
        string name;
    int age;
    string song_list;
       };

       typedef vector <user1> u1;

       struct user2
       {
       string name;
   int age;
   string song_list;
       };
      typedef vector <user2> u2;

       };
```

### help.cpp

```
  #include "Help.h"
  #include "User.h"
  #include <iterator>  
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <algorithm>





  int commonElements();
  int commonElements(){

  vector <user1> u1;
  vector <user2> u2;

  std::sort(u1.begin(), u1.end());
  std::sort(u2.begin(), u2.end());
  std::vector<string> common;

  std::set_intersection(u1.begin(), u1.end(), u2.begin(), u2.end(),                       
  std::back_inserter(common));

   cout<<common<<endl;
   }
```

thats my code so far. All data for the user's name,age and song list is on a .txt file.

Comment: *"nothing works"* is not a sufficient problem description.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be somewhat confused about types vs. instances. You're creating some separate types where (I'm pretty sure) you just want two instances. For example, it appears (to me) that you really want `u1` and `u2` to be vectors of the same type of objects.

user.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct user {
    string name;
    int age;
    vector<string> song_list;
};
```

help.cpp:

```
#include "Help.h"
#include "User.h"
#include <iterator>  
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int commonElements(user &u1, user &u2) {
    sort(u1.song_list.begin(), u1.song_list.end());
    sort(u2.song_list.begin(), u2.song_list.end());
    vector<string> common;

    set_intersection(u1.song_list.begin(), u1.song_list.end(), 
                     u2.song_list.begin(), u2.song_list.end(), 
                     back_inserter(common));

    for (auto const &song : common) 
        cout << song << "\n";

#if 0
    // alternatively, write the intersection directly to the stream:
    set_intersection(u1.song_list.begin(), u1.song_list.end(),
                     u2.song_list.begin(), u2.song_list.end(),
                     ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
#endif
}
```

As an aside, it's generally agreed that putting a `using namespace std;` in a header is a really lousy idea. I've left it because it's mostly unrelated to the question(s) at hand, but it should really be changed.

Comment: int commonElements(user &u1, user &u2)//error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier